# Load a RTFD file on a WebView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, rtf

I want to load a RTFD file (rtf with images) in a WebView.
So I created a file in TextEdit with a text and one image, and saved as `doc.rtfd`

[[image: File created with TextEdit][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOF6p.png)

In order load the file on SwiftUI I tried the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: getURL()! )
        webView.load(request)
    }
    
    public func getURL() -> URL? {
        guard let url: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "doc.rtfd.zip", withExtension: nil) else { return nil }
        return url
    }
}
```

And then:

```
struct ExampleWebView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                WebView( )
                
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .navigationTitle("RTF View")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
           
            Spacer()
        }
    }  
}
```

But as a result, only the text is displayed correctly. For the image only the name (M2.png) is present:

[image: SwiftUI screen]

What I am missing?

Comment: Can you load the RTFD bundle and write its content to a local file to compare it with the original?